# Not able to Reduce Android APK size using Splits

Tags: android, apk, android-ffmpeg

I am using https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android library in my App.
and I found that the Apk size is around 20mb and it contains assets for both in ABI(x86 and armeabi-v7a) in apk using apk analyzer in Android Studio.[find screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBPnw.png)

so Inorder to fix it, I used splits as mentioned in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html)

```
android {...
 splits 
  {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

    // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
    enable true

    // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
    // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

    // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
    reset()

    // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
    include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

    // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal Apk that includes all ABIs.
    universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

it generates two Apks for each ABI, but it's not reducing the app size I used the Apk analyzer to check and its still having the assets for both ABI.

Comment: Better approach would be to use static ffmpeg library and not shared, because shared library is placed inside apk and if you use static library, parts of the used code of library is compiled into apk's .so

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but at least something to consider. You can exclude all the libraries for `x86` and `mips` architectures, since there is no mips devices currently on the market and `x86` devices support `armeabi-v7a` code quite well though Intel Houdini library - that will reduce size significantly.

For the problem with splitting - seems like a bug in Android Studio, since the code is exact the same as in Google Android Docs.